# Cannot Making Outgoing Payments with blockchain.info API v2

Tags: blockchain.info

**I CAN't do Making Outgoing Payments :-(**
i use blockChain api v2 with local nodeJS.
I work with Laravel 5.4. I have VPS server.
I installed local nodeJS service to handle the calls.
I started work of port: node blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3030. 
Then I logined to my wallet.

```
 $url = "http://127.0.0.1:3030/merchant/$guid/login?password=$mainPass&api_code=$myApiKey";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

$ccc = curl_exec($ch);

$json = json_decode($ccc, true);
 var_dump($json);
```

Here, I got a good answer:

```
array(3) { 

   ["guid"]=> string(36) "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx..."

   ["success"]=> bool(true)

   ["message"]=> string(94) "This endpoint has been deprecated. You no longer 
                             have to call /login before accessing a wallet"
 }
```

I can Create Wallet API, check balance, do Listing Addresses, do Generating a new address and do Address Management with positive answers.
**BUT I CAN't do Making Outgoing Payments**. 
I got next answer:

```
 array(1) {
    ["error"]=> string(34)
    "Unexpected error, please try again"
 }
```

Who knews what would be the solution?
I must get Response:

```
 { "message" : "Response Message" , "tx_hash": "Transaction Hash", "notice" : "Additional Message" }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3/issues/108 
Please update your API version and see the link.